# Convert for loop into pandas operations

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-manipulation

I'm wondering if the following can be expressed more cleanly with default pandas operations, how to go about doing so, and whether it would run faster

The data that I have is:

```py
data = {}
sz = 200
data["A"] = np.random.choice([1, 2], size=sz, p=[0.6, 0.4])
data["B"] = np.random.choice(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], size=sz, p=[0.7, 0.11, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.03, 0.01]
)
data["C"] = np.random.normal(loc=0.85, scale=0.57, size=sz)
```

a sample of which looks like:

```
     A  B         C
74   1  1  1.690569
184  2  1  0.808611
67   1  1  0.691865
4    1  1 -0.437749
```

The code that I have is:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

groups = dt.groupby("A")
computed = {}
for group in groups:
    subgroup = group[1].groupby("B")
    sum_of_C = group[1]["C"].sum()
    sum_of_subgroup_C = subgroup["C"].sum()
    cell_values = sum_of_subgroup_C / sum_of_C
    computed[group[0]] = cell_values.mul(100).round(1).to_dict()
    computed[group[0]]["tC"] = round(len(group[1]) * group[1]["C"].mean())
    computed[group[0]]["t"] = len(group[1])
```

Looping over groups doesn't feel very 'pandas', but I'm not sure how I would do the above using just pandas operations.

Comment: might be possible but i dont think that will be any faster than your method.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is the following approach:

```
dt['count'] = 1
dt1= dt.groupby(['A','B'])['C','count'].sum()
dt2 = dt1.groupby('A').sum()    
d1 = (dt1['C']/dt2['C']*100).round(1)
```

Calculations are done now, formatting to get to a similar output as yours:

```
idx3 = pd.Index([d1.index.values,np.full(d1.shape[0],'t')])

d2 = dt2.loc[:,['C']].round()
d2.index=[d2.index.values,np.full(d2.shape[0],'tc')]
d3 = dt2.loc[:,['count']]
d3.columns = ['C']
d3.index = [d3.index.values,np.full(d3.shape[0],'t')]


T = pd.concat([d1,d2,d3],axis=0).sort_index()
```

For large sz (tested for sz = 20000000) the approach above is 10-20% faster, for sz lower than 200000 your approach defeats the above.

You also have one redundant calculation:

```
computed[group[0]]["tC"] = round(len(group[1]) * group[1]["C"].mean())
```

Is actually just:

```
computed[group[0]]["tC"] = sum_of_C
```

I believe the second groupby on the result of the first groupby is faster than looping through like you did before, especially when A has more unique entries.